# Sort array with two infos | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I made code which loads online players from game server(through MySQL table). Now, I'm newbie in PHP and I don't Know how to sort them(users) in table by ID. I googled and I found answer which will sort arrays by value(1, 2, 3, 4 etc..). Only problem is because users, with ID, have a name. How to connect user's name with ID, so they stay together after sort?
Here's a code

```
while($_hsync_podatci = $_hsync_rezultat->fetch_assoc())
{
    ?>
        <tr class="_hsync_online_stil_<?php echo $_hsync_dio; ?>" id="_hsync_na_mrezi_<?php echo $_hsync_podatci['ServerID']; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $_hsync_podatci['ServerID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_hsync_podatci['Ime']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="_hsync_izbaci_<?php echo $_hsync_podatci['ServerID']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="_hsync_izbaci(<?php echo $_hsync_podatci['ServerID']; ?>)" style="float: right;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Izbaci
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        $_hsync_dio = !$_hsync_dio;
}
```

Above while is table's header. Var `$_hsync_dio` is for background color. One row is white, second is grey, and so on.

Comment: add in query `order by ServerID`

Comment: Yes, do as much sorting etc as you can in the query instead of later in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a MySQL query you can sort the array automatically when fetching the data for example:

```
$players = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM playerTable ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($message_sender_info)){
            $message[] = $row;
          }
```

Use DESC instead of ASC for e reverse sorting.